# How to get python to retrieve user-inputted data from a dynamic table using Flask & JINJA2

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

I'm building a Flask app that includes a table where users can change a cell and have those changes 'applied' e.g. updated in the database.

Pictures bellow 
[image]
[image]

I'm having issues getting flask to retrieve this data that has been submitted via form.

The number of rows are dynamic and dependent on the number of Id's in a list.

Here is my html -- sorry for the clunkiness, I am still learning.

```
                            <tbody> 
                            <form method="post" name="productCost">
                        {% for n in range(name_list | length) %}
                            <tr> 
                                <th scope="row" >{{name_list[n]}}</th> 
                                <td>{{ID_list[n]}}</td> 
                                <td id="cost{{n}}">${{cost_list[n]}}</td> 
                                <td>---</td>
                                <td id="changes{{n}}"><button onclick="costChanges{{n}}()">Edit</button></td> 
                            </tr> 
                        <script>
                            function costChanges{{n}}() {
                                document.getElementById("cost{{n}}").innerHTML = "<input placeholder='{{cost_list[n]}}' name={{ID_list[n]}}>";
                                document.getElementById("changes{{n}}").innerHTML = "<button onclick='applyChanges{{n}}()' type='submit'>Apply</button><button onclick='cancelChanges{{n}}()'>Cancel</button>";

                            }
                            function applyChanges{{n}}() {
                                docuemnt.getElementById("cost{{n}}").innerHTML = document.forms["productCost"]["{{ID_list[n]}}"]
                            }
                            function cancelChanges{{n}}() {
                                document.getElementById("cost{{n}}").innerHTML = "{{cost_list[n]}}";
                                document.getElementById("changes{{n}}").innerHTML = "<button onclick='costChanges{{n}}()'>Edit</button>";

                            }
                        </script>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </form>
                        </tbody>
```

Here is my python/flask code:

```
app.route('/expenses', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def expenses():
    if 'email' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login_now'))

    list_of_product_dicts = get_name_id()
    name_list = []
    asin_list =[]
    cost_list=[]
    for p in list_of_product_dicts:
        name_list.append(p['name'])
        id_list.append(p['id'])
        cost = get_landing_cost(p['id'])
        cost_list.append(cost)

    if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.form['name']) 
    return flask.render_template('expenses.html', name_list = name_list, id_list=id_list,
        cost_list=cost_list)
```

I need python to recognize the change that has been made and store it in a variable. This is for the purpose of updating it in a database-- but I do not need assistance with the database code. I only need help getting python to grab the cell that has been changed and recognize what row it was in.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit simpler to use `jquery` with `ajax`. The latter enables you to dynamically update the table by communicating with a backend script to update your database.

First, create the HTML script (the code below creates a different table layout for this example, however, you can substitute your own, based on the one below). The jquery cleanly handles the Apply, Cancel, and Edit button functionalities, and communicates with the backend via `ajax`:

`tables.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <table>
   <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Cost</th>
     <th>Effective Date</th>
     <th>Make Changes</th>
   </tr>
  {%for row in data%}
  <tr>
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td class='cost{{row.rowid}}'>{{row.price}}</td>
    <td>{{row.date}}</td>
    <td>
      <div id='options{{row.rowid}}'>
        <button id='mutate{{row.rowid}}'>Edit</button>
      </div>
    <td>
  </tr>
  {%endfor%}
 </table>
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[id^='options']").on('click', 'button', function(){
   var the_id = this.id.match('\\d+');
   var the_type = this.id.match('[a-zA-Z]+');
   if (the_type == "mutate"){
    $('#options'+the_id).html('<button id="cancel'+the_id+'">Cancel</button>\n<button id="apply'+the_id+'">Apply</button>');
    var current_cost = $('.cost'+the_id).text();
    $('.cost'+the_id).html('\n<input type="text" class="newval'+the_id+'" value="'+current_cost+'">')
   }
   else if (the_type == 'cancel'){
    $('#options'+the_id).html('<button id="mutate'+the_id+'">Edit</button>');
   }
   else{
    var value = $(".newval"+the_id).val();
    $.ajax({
          url: "/update_cell",
          type: "get",
          data: {newval: value, rowid:the_id},
          success: function(response) {
            $('.cost'+the_id).html(value);
            $('#options'+the_id).html('<button id="mutate'+the_id+'">Edit</button>');
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
          }
       });
     }
   });
 });
 </script>
</html>
```

---

Then, create the app and routes:

```
import flask, sqlite3, collections
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
  dummy_data = [['hvVlNnAW', '$6.00', '--'], ['UqBzqLho', '$10.00', '--'], ['tuEdqldI', '$3.00', '--'], ['MIHLFWDS', '$1.00', '--'], ['rUnjpHiJ', '$8.00', '--'], ['lHVHxgZF', '$1.00', '--'], ['nFfaHkHj', '$3.00', '--'], ['rRWqXqVh', '$8.00', '--'], ['rdzCRozr', '$4.00', '--'], ['MGojGbtW', '$9.00', '--']]
  #substitute dummy_data with a database query
  product = collections.namedtuple('product', ['id', 'price', 'date', 'rowid'])
  return flask.render_template('tables.html', data = [product(*a, i) for i, a in enumerate(dummy_data, 1)])

@app.route('/update_cell')
def update_row():
   new_val = flask.request.args.get('newval')
   prod_id = int(flask.request.args.get('rowid[]'))
   #commit new_val to database
   return flask.jsonify({'success':True})
```

Now, in `'/update_cell'`, you have the new price value, and the product row id, which tells you which sqlite row's price you are to update. Note that in `home`, the row id, which is garnered by `enumerate` is vital to the application as it enables the `jquery` to know what table and sqlite row to update.

Demo:

[image]